# Is there a non-remote way to specify geckodriver location when you cannot specify it by System property or Path?

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

In my application I cannot set geckodriver executable location using `System.setProperty` and I cannot set it in the path.

Why? Because my app is multi-tenant... and each tenant has their own directory where Firefox and Geckodriver is copied and ran. This is due to bugs in the Firefox + Geckodriver, where infinite javascript loops and several other situations cause Firefox to hang until manual kill. Sometimes quit fails to kill things completely as well. So we need to supply a custom geckodriver location within the JVM **per-tenant**. Thus the problem.

So I am instead using:

```
driverService = new GeckoDriverService.Builder()
          .usingDriverExecutable(new File(geckoDriverBinaryPath))
          .build();
driverService.start();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(driverServiceUrl, capabilities);
```

But that is making me use a RemoteWebDriver when I am not remote.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just curious: why not using `System.setProperty`?

Comment: my app is multi-tenant. and each tenant has their own directory where Firefox and Geckodriver copied and ran. This is due to bugs in the Firefox + Geckodriver, infinite loops and several other situations cause Firefox to hang until manual `kill`. So we need to supply a custom gecko location within the JVM for each tenant. thus the problem.

Comment: So how do you set `geckoDriverBinaryPath`?

Comment: Copied for each tenant prior to running their job from a central location. and then set in the code snippet in the ticket.

Comment: Without knowing more about your process, have you tried passing this in as a variable? Read it using `System.getenv(name)`.

Comment: Hey SiKing can you elaborate more on that? i'm not really clear what you are asking me to try here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling `start()` on the `FirefoxDriverService` object, why not simply use the `FirefoxDriver` constructor that takes the service?

```
driverService = new GeckoDriverService.Builder()
      .usingDriverExecutable(new File(geckoDriverBinaryPath))
      .build();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService);
```

Comment: ah! had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

As the questions stands it is still too broad. There are some unknowns: How are you running this? JUnit?, Maven?, Jenkins? And I am still not clear where this *per-tenat* `geckoDriverBinaryPath` comes from and how it is passed around.

What is wrong with just using:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverBinaryPath);
```

You could set an environment variable in your OS. Something like `export geckoDriverBinary=/some/path` and then in your code read it back using:

```
String geckoDriverBinaryPath = System.getenv("geckoDriverBinary");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverBinaryPath);
...
```

If you are running it from command line, either straight up or using Maven, you could pass the variable in like `-DgeckoDriverBinaryPath=/some/path` and then in your code read it back using:

```
String geckoDriverBinaryPath = System.getProperty("geckoDriverBinary");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverBinaryPath);
...
```

If the different tenants have the path fixed, you could write a utility function that would detect which tenant it is being run on, and set the property accordingly.

This answer is probably going to get closed as not-answer, but more of a discussion. :(

Comment: i mean, the question did state that i cannot do exactly what you suggest but i like your line of thought here. don't give up on it.